# How do users who navigate using a keyboard change the style of the text they are editing in ckeditor5

Tags: accessibility, ckeditor5

Disabled users who cannot control a mouse use the keyboard to navigate the page. How do you allow them to select the various styles (like bold etc) in ckeditor5? These elements are NOT in the tabindex of the page by default.

Tabbing through a form, I expect to be able to interact with every interactable element on a page

Answer (score 1):

I see that CKEditor 5 has [a list of keyboard shortcuts](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/keyboard-support.html.) in their documentation.  Pressing Alt + F10 (may require Fn) when the editor input area has focus moves keyboard focus to the editor toolbar. Then, keyboard arrow keys can be used to navigate the toolbar.
I am not saying that CKEditor is accessible, but it is information you may consider.

Answer (score 0):

[WCAG 2.1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#keyboard) says that all **functionality** must be available from the keyboard.  Sometimes people mistakenly interpret that to mean that all interactive elements on the page must be keybaord accessible.

Here's a screenshot of ckeditor5 from their [website](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/).  I'm not a ckeditor5 user but I'm assuming you're talking about the editing bar at the top.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

While it's strongly encouraged to allow a keyboard user to navigate to the editing bar of ckeditor5, it's not strictly required if all the **functionality** of the editing bar is available via the keyboard.

For example, if I can select text then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to make it bold, then the functionality of bold is available even if I can't <kbd>tab</kbd> to the 'B' on the editor bar.

The editing bar has a lot of stuff on it so everything would need a keyboard shortcut in order to pass WCAG 2.1.1.  It looks like you can configure ckedit5 pretty extensively, https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

The docs on [CKEditor keyboard support](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/keyboard-support.html) will list the possible keyboard controls to format text.

- Text can be selected with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + the arrow keys
- and formatted bold with <kbd>Ctrl + b</kbd>
- for more options the menubar can be focused with <kbd>Shift + F10</kbd>

For web applications, the idea is to follow the desktop application’s keyboard conventions, so that users of assistive technology don’t need to learn yet another interaction paradigm.

The example to look at for rich text editors on Windows would probably be Word or Wordpad. There are two ways to format text.

### Shortcut to open the menubar

The [Menu bar pattern on the ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/menu/#keyboard-interaction-12) specifically mentions rich text editors in a note:

> For example, a rich text editor may have a menubar that receives focus when a shortcut key, e.g., <kbd>alt + F10</kbd>, is pressed while editing.  In this case, pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> or activating a command from the menu may return focus to the editor.

For any common pattern you should find recommendations for the keyboard interface on the APG. Since it’s platform-independent (not only for Windows), such shortcuts will only be found in notes.

### Shortcuts for formatting directly

Selected text can often be formatted directly by pressing  + a letter for the English abbreviation of the format, like i for Italic or b for Bold.

CKEditor supports these.